# AWS CodeDeploy Keeps Failing - failed to find platform: no manifest

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to troubleshoot, why my deployments using AWS code-pipeline is failing. I am using AWS code-deploy to deploy from S3.

I have a EC2 instance with CentOS 8 server, with architecture x86_64 and the app is a website running on Nginx

My appspec.yml looks like this:

```
version: 0.1
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/html/
```

The reason why it fails from the log located in  **/var/log/amazon/ssm/amazon-ssm-agent.log**

***2021-03-06 17:11:22 ERROR [logTraceDone @ trace.go.100] [ssm-document-worker] [18633a65-1007-4d73-b43b-54e7b06001d9] [DataBackend] [pluginName=aws:configurePackage] done with ensure package is locally available - error: failed to find platform: no manifest found for platform: centos, version 8, architecture x86_64***

```
"runtimeStatus": {
    "configurePackage": {
      "status": "Failed",
      "code": 1,
      "name": "aws:configurePackage",
      "output": "\n----------ERROR-------\nfailed to find platform: no manifest found for platform: centos, version 8, architecture x86_64\nfailed to find platform: no manifest found for platform: centos, version 8, architecture x86_64\nfailed to find platform: no manifest found for platform: centos, version 8, architecture x86_64\nfailed to find platform: no manifest found for platform: centos, version 8, architecture x86_64\n",
      "startDateTime": "2021-03-06T11:41:17.471Z",
      "endDateTime": "2021-03-06T11:41:22.047Z",
      "outputS3BucketName": "",
      "outputS3KeyPrefix": "",
      "stepName": "",
      "standardOutput": "",
      "standardError": "failed to find platform: no manifest found for platform: centos, version 8, architecture x86_64\nfailed to find platform: no manifest found for platform: centos, version 8, architecture x86_64\nfailed to find platform: no manifest found for platform: centos, version 8, architecture x86_64\nfailed to find platform: no manifest found for platform: centos, version 8, architecture x86_64\n"
    }
```

Also if I do deployment status log using cli  **aws deploy get-deployment-instance --deployment-id d-id --instance-id i-id**

I get the error as

```
{
    "instanceSummary": {
        "deploymentId": "d-id",
        "instanceId": "arn:aws:ec2:.............",
        "status": "Failed",
        "lastUpdatedAt": 1615032216.643,
        "lifecycleEvents": [
            {
                "lifecycleEventName": "ApplicationStop",
                "startTime": 1615032216.503,
                "endTime": 1615032216.503,
                "status": "Failed"
            },
            {
                "lifecycleEventName": "DownloadBundle",
                "status": "Skipped"
            },
            {
                "lifecycleEventName": "BeforeInstall",
                "status": "Skipped"
            },
            {
                "lifecycleEventName": "Install",
                "status": "Skipped"
            },
            {
                "lifecycleEventName": "AfterInstall",
                "status": "Skipped"
            },
            {
                "lifecycleEventName": "ApplicationStart",
                "status": "Skipped"
            },
            {
                "lifecycleEventName": "ValidateService",
                "status": "Skipped"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Any idea on what is the root cause of this problem and what is the solution for this?